# Display the textboxes results in Excel sheet cells in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have two textboxes on a form; one hold the word and the other one holds its numeric value that is calculated based on what the user types. I have a sub that separates each sentence and displays the total for each sentence in Excel. This is the output that being generated from the vb.net code which is listed below. All the words are in A column and all the values in B column.  How do I modify the code so it inserts each sentence and its value in two columns? After it reaches the string "Total for sentence 1." it should start inserting the words and its values in columns C & D and so forth.
Sentence one and its value should be displayed in columns A & B, sentence two and its value should be displayed in columns C & D and so on.
Please see the attached image. Text in red is what I currently have and below it is the desired result. Thanks![image]

My Code in vb.net is:

```
Private Sub Export_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

    xlApp.Visible = True

    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim columnANum As Integer
    Dim columnBNum
    columnBNum = 2
    columnANum = 2
    With xlWorkSheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Word"
        For Each cellA As String In txtWord.Text.Split(vbLf)

            .Range("A" & columnANum.ToString).Value = cellA
            columnANum += 1
        Next
        .Range("B1").Value = "Value"
        For Each cellB As String In txtValue.Text.Split(vbLf)
            .Range("B" & columnBNum.ToString).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cellB)
            columnBNum += 1
        Next


    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I made significant changes to this code and tested it; it should do what you're looking for

```
Sub testExcelColumns()
    Dim xlApp As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim xlWorkBook As Object
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Object

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True

    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim RowNum As Integer = 1
    Dim ColNum As Integer = 1

    'use .cells(row, column) instead of .range
    xlWorkSheet.cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = "Word"

    For Each cellA As String In txtWord.Text.Split(vbLf)

        'increment the row
        RowNum += 1

        'set the value
        xlWorkSheet.cells(RowNum, ColNum).value = cellA

        If cellA.StartsWith("Total") Then
            ColNum += 2
            RowNum = 1
            xlWorkSheet.cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = "Word"
        End If

    Next

    'increment to the second column and first row
    ColNum = 2
    RowNum = 1

    'set title
    xlWorkSheet.cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = "Value"

    For Each cellB As String In txtValue.Text.Split(vbLf)

        'increment the row
        RowNum += 1

        'set the value
        xlWorkSheet.cells(RowNum, ColNum).value = cellB

        'get value of cell to the left
        Dim t As String = xlWorkSheet.cells(RowNum, ColNum).offset(0, -1).value
        If Not t Is Nothing AndAlso t.StartsWith("Total") Then
            ColNum += 2
            RowNum = 1
            xlWorkSheet.cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = "Value"
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: When I ran the code, I got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object vb.net" error on line that starts with if.t.StartWith("Total" Then. Also, the values are inserted in column B only, they do not loop and go to the next column like B, E, etc. Also, the title word is not carried over to the next column like C. The title Value is not populated at all. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object vb.net" is because sometimes t will be nothing. Test for that case like this: If Not t Is Nothing AndAlso t.StartsWith("Total") Then

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Dim RowNum as Integer = 1
Dim ColNum as Integer = 1
```

use .cells instead of .range

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowNum, ColNum).value = "Word"
xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowNum, ColNum).value = "Value"
```

update the row and column as needed

```
RowNum += 1
ColNum += 1
```

Comment: xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).value = "Word"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2).value = "Value"
        For Each cellA As String In txtWord.Text.Split(vbLf)
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowNum, 1).value = cellA
How do iMove to the next columns which are C & D if the cell value in column A = "Total"?
            RowNum += 1
            ColNum += 2
        Next
        RowNum = 2
        For Each cellB As String In txtValue.Text.Split(vbLf)

            xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowNum, 2).value = cellB
            RowNum += 1
            ColNum += 2
        Next