# Loop through Excel columns and insert values

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have two text boxes on a form. One has string or the other one has values that are separated by vbnewline. Once it reaches the string "Total" in the text box, it should insert the string after two columns. If I am inserting in column A and reached the cell that equals = "Total" it should start inserting the strings in column C and the values in column D and so forth. Right now the code below inserts everything in two columns only (A & B) without going to the next columns. How do I start inserting the the strings and values in the next columns like (C & D), (E, & F) and so on when cell value is equal to "Total"?

```
Dim RowNum As Integer = 2
Dim ColNum As Integer = 1



    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).value = "Word"
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2).value = "Value"
    For Each cellA As String In txtWord.Text.Split(vbLf)
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowNum, ColNum).value = cellA
        RowNum += 1
        If xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowNum, ColNum).value = "Total" Then
            ColNum += 2
        End If
    Next
    RowNum = 2
    For Each cellB As String In txtValue.Text.Split(vbLf)

        xlWorkSheet.Cells(RowNum, 2).value = cellB
        RowNum += 1
        ColNum += 2
    Next
```

Comment: You should edit your post to ask a specific question, and to tell us something about the code you have posted. Does it work? What errors do you receive? What does it currently do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same question as you asked previously. See: [Display the textboxes results in Excel sheet cells in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519768/display-the-textboxes-results-in-excel-sheet-cells-in-vb-net)

You can check out my revised answer there.